# Is there a way to save an @Entity with pre-defined @EmbeddedId value using Spring Data's CrudRepository#save() method?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, composite-primary-key

I'm creating a new service with the goal of consuming Kafka events in an idempotent manner and storing the data into a new PostgreSQL database.

The event will provide data which will be used in the composite key:

```java
@Embeddable
public class MyCompositeKey implements Serializable {

    @Column(name="field1", nullable = false)
    private UUID field1;

    @Column(name="field2", nullable = false)
    private UUID field2;

    @Column(name="field3", nullable = false)
    private UUID field3;

... boilerplate Constructors/getters ...
```

And the Entity will be referencing it via `@EmbeddedId`:

```java
@Entity
@Table
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {

  @EmbeddedId private MyCompositeKey myCompositeKey;

... Columns/Constructors/getters ...
```

When an event is consumed, I want to let `spring-data-jpa` be smart enough to know whether we are replacing data from an existing MyEntity, or creating a new row.

The logic was deemed safe enough to use the `CrudRepository#save` method before researching the expectation of the logic within that method:

```java
    @Transactional
    public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {
        if (this.entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
            this.em.persist(entity);
            return entity;
        } else {
            return this.em.merge(entity);
        }
    }
```

I've gotten to the point where the transactions appear to be completed, but no records are persisted to the table.

I've confirmed via debugging that the call to `#save` is branching into the `return this.em.merge(entity)` logic referenced above.

I've only found one possibly helpful blog post[1] for a similar scenario, and am lost on where to go next after it didn't seem to resolve the issue.

The only other option I can foresee is to manually go through a potential three-query execution:

1. `findById`
2. if exists, `delete`
3. `save`

### Components

- spring-boot-starter 2.0.6
- spring-boot-starter-data-jpa 2.0.6
- hibernate 5.2.x

### References

[1] https://jivimberg.io/blog/2018/11/05/using-uuid-on-spring-data-jpa-entities/

Comment: the merge should update the state in the database with the state from your object once the changes got flushed which happens when the transaction is committed. If it doesn't I would consider this a Hibernate bug. Create a reproducer and file an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I found the issue. All of this design was working fine, it was the configuration which was missing.

For some context - Spring Boot seems to configure default `javax.sql.DataSource`, default `javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory`, and default `org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager` beans.

My context was configured with a `javax.sql.DataSource` bean in order to specify a configuration prefix distinction using `org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties`.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.myservice"})
public class RepositoryConfiguration {

  @Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myservice.datasource")
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
  }
}
```

My context did *not* add in replacements for the dependent `javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory` and `org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager` beans.

The fix was to add in all of the configuration. From the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.java-config):

> You must create LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean and not EntityManagerFactory directly, since the former also participates in exception translation mechanisms in addition to creating EntityManagerFactory.

The resulting configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.myservice"})
public class RepositoryConfiguration {

  @Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myservice.datasource")
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
  }

  @Bean
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {

    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    factory.setPackagesToScan("com.myservice");
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    return factory;
  }

  @Bean
  public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
    return txManager;
  }
}
```